# How do you format a number to truncate the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, format

I am looking to format number to output in a graph and would like to ideally use the following structure to output only the amount in millions.

```
'{v:,.2f}'.format(v=val)
```

and using a similar structure I would like to take a number like `120,568,090.23` and return `120` or `121`. Round vs. truncate does not matter too much too me.

Thanks

Comment: You can do your own function, split by "," check if nex value is bigger or lower than 5

Comment: Can't you just do `'{v:,.2f}'.format(v=(val/1000000))`?

Comment: Yes (with .0 not .2). Python 3.6 or later can use an f-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```py
>>> '{v:,.0f}'.format(v=val/1000000)
121
```

Answer (score 1):

Rounded division

```
f"{val/1000000:.0f}"
```

will output `121`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a floor division of your number:

```py
x = 120,568,090.23

print( x // 10**6)
```

Which returns 120.0